# How to handle a wide variety of object types for the same data

Tags: oop, architecture, software-design, readability, code-complexity

I am building an application which uses a lot of vectors and for which I am using a lot of third party and system assemblies. The result of this is that I have four ways to to represent 3d double precision vectors, and five ways to represent collections of those vectors. This is true for just about everything I have. The result is that I need to handle 30 different types for about three different actual structures. From your experience, what is the cleanest way to handle this?

Comment: When you're working with the different systems, is the exchange one-way (i.e. saved into your system) or bi-directional (you save them into your system, and also have to pass them back out to the other systems)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the other systems are providing vector data to your application, and the transfer is just one-way (into your app), then all you have to do is decide how you want to store / handle vectors in your app, and when data comes in simply convert it to that format.  The conversion is a one-time thing, and once it's converted you only have the one format to worry about.

(The same architecture can handle two-way interactions - let me cover that last).

This is where Dependency Inversion comes in handy, because you can write different modules where each one is dedicated to work with a specific 3rd party system, and load up the appropriate one at runtime.

[image]

Diagram / architecture explained:

1. **External Vector Service** - the sub-system or layer that handles the incoming data from the 3rd party systems.
2. **Service Logic** - the code that handles / coordinates what the External Vector Service does.
3. **IExternalVectorProvider** an interface that describes the operations you need to support, e.g. "SaveFunkyVectors", "SaveDoubleProjectionVector".
4. **SystemA_VectorProvider**, **SystemB_VectorProvider** and **SystemC_VectorProvider** - the 3rd party specific classes that implement IExternalVectorProvider.
5. **Dependency Injection Sub-System** - at runtime, loads the right IExternalVectorProvider implementation into the Service Logic.

So for example:

- your app identifies that it's talking to 3rd Party System A and loads up the correct module (SystemA_VectorProvider) into the service logic.
- This  allows your app to interact with 3rd Party System A, using the vector format that System A understands.
- Once SystemA_VectorProvider has the data, it converts it to your standard format, and passes that back up to the service logic, and on to any other part of your app.

I put the dependency injection in the main part of the app because ideally it'll be generic and you can reuse it elsewhere.

**What about Bi-Directional?**

The exact same architecture can be used - as long as your IExternalVectorProvider set-up can re-format data from your standard back to the target 3rd party one.